# JSeparator wont show with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, gridbaglayout

I want to add a vertical JSeparator between two components using a GridBagLayout. The code I have is as follows:

```
public MainWindowBody(){
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    JPanel leftPanel = new InformationPanel();
    JPanel rightPanel = new GameSelectionPanel();

    JSeparator sep = new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

    add(leftPanel,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;

    add(sep,gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

    add(rightPanel,gbc);
}
```

But the JSeperator doesn't show, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The JSeperator does actually "show", there's a thin line between the components which will go away if you comment out add(sep,gbc)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try to set the preferred width for the separator:

```
sep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5,1));
```

Then, make GridBagLayout use up all available height for the separator:

```
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
gbc.weighty = 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

Taken from **Sun's** guide for `JSeparator`:

> In most implementations, a vertical
>   separator has a preferred height of 0,
>   and a horizontal separator has a
>   preferred width of 0. This means a
>   separator is not visible unless you
>   either set its preferred size or put
>   it in under the control of a layout
>   manager such as BorderLayout or
>   BoxLayout that stretches it to fill
>   its available display area.
>
> The vertical separator does have a bit
>   of width (and the horizontal a bit of
>   height), so you should see some space
>   where the separator is. However, the
>   actual dividing line isn't drawn
>   unless the width and height are both
>   non-zero.

Maybe you should set right constraints?

Comment: is there any way under the grid bag layout i can make it stretch to the height of the window?