# Vertical JSeparator incorrectly positioned by GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, positioning, gridbaglayout

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425729/jseparator-wont-show-with-gridbaglayout).

I'm trying to create a window with two panels that have widths in the ratio 2:1 (with the left-side panel wider than the right-side one) and I'm using the GridBagLayout.

Basically, something that looks like this:

```
 ____________________
|            |       |
| leftPanel  |right- |
|            |Panel  |
|         |->|       |
|_________|__|_______|
          |
          |
     both panels separated
     by a vertical separator
```

Here is the code that creates the top-level `JPanel` (I've called it `totalGui`) holding both `leftPanel` and `rightPanel`:

```
private JPanel createContentPane(){ //creates a top-level JPanel
                                    //that is returned to the JFrame's
                                    //setContentPane() method
    int WINHEIGHT = 600;
    int WINWIDTH = 800;
    JPanel totalGui = new JPanel(); //this is the JPanel that will be returned
    totalGui.setBackground(Color.white);
    totalGui.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    totalGui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    totalGui.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    totalGui.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    totalGui.setOpaque(true);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    /* totalGui (the top-level JPane) has two JPanes called
       leftPanel and rightPanel. The widths of leftPanel and rightPanel
       are in the ratio 2:1. So, leftPanel takes up 2/3rd of the totalGui's
       width, and rightPanel gets the remaining 1/3rd */

    /* Top-level left panel */
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    int LEFTPANELWIDTH = WINWIDTH*2/3;
    leftPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(LEFTPANELWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(LEFTPANELWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    leftPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(LEFTPANELWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridheight=4; //both leftPanel and rightPanel are 4 cells high
    c.gridwidth=2; //leftPanel is 2 cells wide, rightPanel is 1 cell wide (code below)
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    totalGui.add(leftPanel, c);

    /* Vertical separator between leftPanel and rightPanel */
    c.gridx = 2; //'2' because leftPanel is 2 cells wide and the separator's leading
                 //edge must lie in the third cell (gridx = 2) if it is to be
                 //sandwiched between leftPanel and rightPanel
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth=0; //I've also tried gridwidth=1, but it doesn't solve the problem
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    c.anchor=GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    JSeparator verticalsep = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
    verticalsep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(6,WINHEIGHT-10)); //the 'WINHEIGHT-10' bit is purely cosmetic
                                                                 //I just wanted some space between the
                                                                 //separator edges and the window border
                                                                 //(also why the anchor is set to CENTER)
    totalGui.add(verticalsep,c); //PROBLEM: verticalsep is not displayed where I expected it to be;
                                 //please see attached image in post

    /* Top-level right panel */
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    int RIGHTPANELWIDTH = WINWIDTH*1/3;
    rightPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    rightPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(RIGHTPANELWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(RIGHTPANELWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    rightPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(RIGHTPANELWIDTH,WINHEIGHT));
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth=1; //rightPanel is 1 cell wide, leftPanel is 2 cells wide (code above)
    c.gridheight=4; //both leftPanel and rightPanel are 4 cells high
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    totalGui.add(rightPanel, c);

    return totalGui;
}
```

My problem is that the separator is not being shown at the correct location. Here's what I get: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRww2.png) (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have used `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` instead of `GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL`. Try this one and you'll get the following result (separator is red):
[image]

```
package com.denisk.fun.swing;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Date: Mar 6, 2011
 * Time: 9:11:03 AM
 *
 * @author denisk
 */
public class GridBagLayoutTest extends JFrame {
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagLayoutDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        frame.setContentPane(createContentPane());
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static Container createContentPane() {
        int WINHEIGHT = 600;
        int WINWIDTH = 800;
        JPanel totalGui = new JPanel(); //this is the JPanel that will be returned
        totalGui.setBackground(Color.white);
        totalGui.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        totalGui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        totalGui.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WINWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        totalGui.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        totalGui.setOpaque(true);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        /* totalGui (the top-level JPane) has two JPanes called
               leftPanel and rightPanel. The widths of leftPanel and rightPanel
               are in the ratio 2:1. So, leftPanel takes up 2/3rd of the totalGui's
               width, and rightPanel gets the remaining 1/3rd */

        /* Top-level left panel */
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        int LEFTPANELWIDTH = WINWIDTH * 2 / 3;
        leftPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(LEFTPANELWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(LEFTPANELWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        leftPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(LEFTPANELWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 4; //both leftPanel and rightPanel are 4 cells high
        c.gridwidth = 2; //leftPanel is 2 cells wide, rightPanel is 1 cell wide (code below)
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        totalGui.add(leftPanel, c);

        /* Vertical separator between leftPanel and rightPanel */
        c.gridx = 2; //'2' because leftPanel is 2 cells wide and the separator's leading
        //edge must lie in the third cell (gridx = 2) if it is to be
        //sandwiched between leftPanel and rightPanel
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 0; //I've also tried gridwidth=1, but it doesn't solve the problem
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        JSeparator verticalsep = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        verticalsep.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 102));
        verticalsep.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(6, WINHEIGHT - 10)); //the 'WINHEIGHT-10' bit is purely cosmetic
        //I just wanted some space between the
        //separator edges and the window border
        //(also why the anchor is set to CENTER)
        totalGui.add(verticalsep, c); //PROBLEM: verticalsep is not displayed where I expected it to be;
        //please see attached image in post

        /* Top-level right panel */
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        int RIGHTPANELWIDTH = WINWIDTH * 1 / 3;
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        rightPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(RIGHTPANELWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        rightPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(RIGHTPANELWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        rightPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(RIGHTPANELWIDTH, WINHEIGHT));
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1; //rightPanel is 1 cell wide, leftPanel is 2 cells wide (code above)
        c.gridheight = 4; //both leftPanel and rightPanel are 4 cells high
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        totalGui.add(rightPanel, c);

        return totalGui;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, since my panels (as well as the separator) are as high as the window/parent `JPanel` (effectively leaving nothing to _constrain_), the constraint comes in along the other axis. That makes sense. I've accepted your answer, many thanks.