# I can't see Swing JSeparator

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jseparator

I have this code:

```
  JPanel jpMainExample = new JPanel(new java.awt.FlowLayout(java.awt.FlowLayout.LEFT));
  jpMainExample.add(new JLabel("JLabel"));
  jpMainExample.add(new JTextField("JTextField"));
  jpMainExample.add(new JSeparator(JSeparator.VERTICAL));
  jpMainExample.add(new JRadioButton("JRadioButton"));
  jpMainExample.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL));
  jpMainExample.add(new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"JComboBox"}));
  jpOUT.add(jpMainExample);
```

But, I can't see the separator.

[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425729/jseparator-wont-show-with-gridbaglayout . It addresses a different layout, but may help.

Comment: *"I can't see the separator."* In some PLAFs, a separator is invisible (but still takes up space). How does the component placement appear without the separators?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preferredSize of the separator is (2, 0). A FlowLayout respects the preferred size. Since the height is 0, there is nothing to paint.

So you need to use a different layout manager that will resize the component to fill the space available vertically.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Separators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html) for a working example. It shows how to use a `BoxLayout`.

Comment: One can also just set the the minimum size of the separator with setMinimumSize(). This works at least for FlowLayout.